# How to extract user defined region from an fasta file with a list in other file

Tags: python, bash, perl, bioinformatics, fasta

I have a multi-fasta sequence file: test.fasta

```
>Ara_001
MGIKGLTKLLADNAPSCMKEQKFESYFGRKIAVDASMSIYQFLIVVGRTGTEMLTNEAGE
VTSHLQGMFNRTIRLLEAGIKPVYVFDGKPPELKRQELAKRYSKRADATADLTGAIEAGN
>Ara_002
MGIKGLTKLLADNAPSCMKEQKFESYFGRKIAVDASMSIYQFLIVVGRTGTEMLTNEAGE
VTSHLQGMFNRTIRLLEAGIKPVYVFDGKPPELKRQELAKRYSKRADATADLTGAIEAGN
>Ara_003
MGIKGLTKLLAEHAPRAAAQRRVEDYRGRVIAIDASLSIYQFLVVVGRKGTEVLTNEAEG
LTVDCYARFVFDGEPPDLKKRELAKRSLRRDDASEDLNRAIEVGDEDSIEKFSKRTVKIT
```

I have another list file with a range: range.txt

```
Ara_001       3 60
Ara_002       10 80
Ara_003       20 50
```

I want to extract the defined region.

My expected out put would be:

```
>Ara_001
KGLTKLLADNAPSCMKEQKFESYFGRKIAVDASMSIYQFLIVVGRTGTEMLTNEAGE
VT
>Ara_002
ADNAPSCMKEQKFESYFGRKIAVDASMSIYQFLIVVGRTGTEMLTNEAGE
VTSHLQGMFNRTIRLLEAGIKPVYVFDGKP
>Ara_003
RRVEDYRGRVIAIDASLSIYQFLVVVGRKG
```

I tried:

```
#!/bin/bash
lines=$(awk 'END {print NR}' range.txt)
for ((a=1; a<= $lines ; a++))
 do
 number=$(awk -v lines=$a 'NR == lines' range.txt)
 grep -v ">" test.fasta | awk -v lines=$a 'NR == lines' | cut -c$number
done;
```

Comment: please update the question with more details ... where does `$number` come from? what do the 2 numbers in `range.txt` refer to - a start position and end position - a start position and length of string to extract - something else; and how do the 2 numbers apply across lines from the fasta file?

Comment: also consider reviewing [How do I format my posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and then update your question with proper formatting; looking at your question history it also appears you may want to review [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and then consider reviewing your question history

Answer (score 2):

Do not reinvent the wheel. Use standard bioinformatics tools written for this purpose and used widely. In your example, use [`bedtools getfasta`](https://bedtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/tools/getfasta.html). Reformat your regions file to be in 3-column [bed](https://genome.ucsc.edu/FAQ/FAQformat.html#format1) format, then:

```
bedtools getfasta -fi test.fasta -bed range.bed
```

Install `bedtools` suite, for example, using [`conda`](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/index.html), specifically `miniconda`, like so:

```
conda create --name bedtools bedtools
```

Answer (score 0):

When I wrote my initial answer I misunderstood the question. Your situation is not so much dependent on any programming languages. You seem to need the utility in Timur Shtatland's answer. Either install that utility or use mozway's python code snippet which handles *both* of your files.

I read the format of your question as if you had 4 individual files, not two.

Comment: Dear PixelBlurb, Thank you for the quick help. With ./extract.py test.fasta, I am getting File "extract.py", line 10, in <module>
    tmp = open(list_[0], 'r')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '>Ara_001'

Answer (score 0):

Using biopython:

```
# read ranges as dictionary
with open('range.txt') as f:
    ranges = {ID: (int(start), int(stop)) for ID, start, stop in map(lambda s: s.strip().split(), f)}
# {'Ara_001': (3, 60), 'Ara_002': (10, 80), 'Ara_003': (20, 50)}

# load input fasta and slice
from Bio import SeqIO
with open ('test.fasta') as handle:
    out = [r[slice(*ranges[r.id])] for r in SeqIO.parse(handle, 'fasta')]

# export sliced sequences
with open('output.fasta', 'w') as handle:
    SeqIO.write(out, handle, 'fasta')
```

Output file:

```
>Ara_001
KGLTKLLADNAPSCMKEQKFESYFGRKIAVDASMSIYQFLIVVGRTGTEMLTNEAGE
>Ara_002
ADNAPSCMKEQKFESYFGRKIAVDASMSIYQFLIVVGRTGTEMLTNEAGEVTSHLQGMFN
RTIRLLEAGI
>Ara_003
RRVEDYRGRVIAIDASLSIYQFLVVVGRKG
```

*NB. With this quick code there must be a entry for each sequence id in range.txt, it's however quite easy to modify it to use a default behavior on case of absence of it.*

Comment: Hi mozway, I am getting following error:  ./extract_region.py: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./extract_region.py: line 2: `with open('region.txt') as f:'

Comment: What is the full error traceback and did you use the same files as provided?

Answer (score 0):

With [Biotite](https://www.biotite-python.org/), a package I am developing, this can be done with:

```py
import biotite.sequence.io.fasta as fasta

input_file = fasta.FastaFile.read("test.fasta")
output_file = fasta.FastaFile()

with open("range.txt") as file:
    for line in file.read().splitlines():
        seq_id, start, stop = line.split()
        start = int(start)
        stop = int(stop)
        output_file[seq_id] = input_file[seq_id][start : stop]

output_file.write("path/to/output.fasta")
```